# Combining two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have two dictionaries.

```
Dictionary 1 looks like this: {'aaien': ['01, 02, 12'], 'aan': ['10']}
Dictionary 2 looks like this: {'01:': ['pronoun'], '02': ['I'],'03': ['we']}
```

And now I want to write a function or a code that combines this two dictionaries and the result should be: 
'aaien':['pronoun, I, affect']

This is what I've got so far:

```
for word, nums in d1.items():
    print word, "->",
    for num in nums:
        if d2.has_key(num):
            print d2[num],
    print
```

Comment: Are you sure you got all the quotes right in the examples?

Comment: Also, where does `affect` come from?

Comment: So you're not really combining the dictionaries, but using one as a lookup to replace values in another?

Comment: affect is the word that comes with the number 12...

Comment: Yes willOEM, that's right... but i'm a beginner and i haven't go a clue how to start with a lookup, followed by replacing values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you fix your dicts first, and use `dict.setdefault` after:

```
d1 = {k:map(str.strip,v[0].split(',')) for k,v in d1.iteritems()}
d2 = {k.strip(':'):v for k,v in d2.iteritems()}

result = {}
for k,v in d1.iteritems():
    for i in v:
        if i in d2:
            result.setdefault(k,[]).extend(d2[i])
print result
```

*output:*

```
{'aaien': ['pronoun', 'I']}
```

Answer (score 1):

using `collections.defaultdict()`:

```
In [60]: dic1= {'aaien': ['01, 02, 12'], 'aan': ['10']}

In [61]: dic2={'01': ['pronoun'], '02': ['I'],'03': ['we']}   #  after fixing '01:'

In [62]: dic3=defaultdict(list)

In [63]: for x,y in dic1.items():
    keys=map(str.strip,y[0].split(","))  #split at ",", and then apply str.strip
    for k in keys:                        
        if k in dic2:                    #if key is present in dic2
            dic3[x].extend(dic2[k])
   ....:             

In [64]: dic3
Out[64]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'aaien': ['pronoun', 'I']})
```

Comment: +1. But you don't really need the `if k in dic2:`; you can just `dic3[x].extend(dic2.get(k, []))`.

Comment: 0@abarnert But it'll add something like `'aan':[]` as well.

Comment: Actually, that's what I thought the OP wanted, and I didn't think about the fact that your version wouldn't do that… You're right, they're different, and I have no idea which on the OP actually wants given the incomplete data. So, never mind.

Comment: Sorry, I have to think about it a little more.. The task that I need to do is so complicated that I'm having difficulties with figuring out what exactly needs to be done.. So before I can say anything more, I have to think... I wish I knew more about Python already

Answer (score 0):

After you "fix" your dicts first (as others have suggested) 
I'm hoping they would look like this.

```
d1 = {'aaien': ['01', '02', '12'], 'aan': ['10']}
d2 = {'01': 'pronoun', '02': 'I', '03': 'we'}
```

then try this:

```
print {k: [d2.get(l) for l in v] for k, v in d1.iteritems()}
{'aaien': ['pronoun', 'I', None], 'aan': [None]}
```

values have been substituted and None put where there is no value available.

if you really meant to have your lookup dict(d2) values be lists of values I'd need more info.  Are you wanting lists of lists or flattened out?

ie. with a lookup of

```
d2 = {'01': ['pronoun'], '02': ['I', 'spam'], '03': ['we']}
```

you want which of these

```
{'aaien': ['pronoun', 'I', 'spam', None], 'aan': [None]}
{'aaien': ['pronoun', ['I', 'spam'], None], 'aan': [None]}
```

Comment: I have to think about it a little more.. The task that I need to do is so complicated that I'm having difficulties with figuring out what exactly needs to be done.. So before I can say anything more, I have to think... I wish I knew more about Python already